# Spilit String in View or store Procedure In Sql Server 2014

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have one table in which i stored values with pipe shine("|").i want to create inner join in which i use value in table ..
so how i firstly split value from table column and after split that value pass to inner join query and get data.
here i upload some images of my table and columns.
can anyone suggest how can i do this in sql server 2014
thanks in advance

**Separate "|" By Column Table Name TDCWax**

[image: Separate "|" By Column Table Name TDCWax]

**Inner Join Separtae Value to Metalcode for MetalDetails table**

[image: inner Join Separtae Value to Metalcode for MetalDetails table]

Comment: Use charindex and substring to extract the string you want then assign it a column name. Wrap the whole thing up in a subquery. Then you can query that subquery as a table which you can inner join with other tables.

Comment: MySQL or SQL Server ?

Comment: Sql Server 2014

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I see you are using SQL Server 2014

Since there is not a build-in solution provided by SQL Server to split requirements, you should use user defined SQL functions which are created for this task.

If you have the chance to use SQL Server 2016, it has a native SQL Split function [String_Split](http://www.kodyaz.com/t-sql/split-string-function-in-sqlserver-2016.aspx)

Please check following: [SQL split function](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/t-sql-convert-split-delimeted-string-as-rows-using-xml.aspx) with For XML Path, [CLR string split function](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/sql-server-string-split-tsql-clr-function-sample.aspx)

All functions can be used as follows

```
SELECT val FROM dbo.Split(N'a|b|c|d|e', '|')
```

If you want to split a value stored in a table column, then you can use CROSS APPLY with the output of the SPLIT table function

```
--create table splitstring (id int identity(1,1), string nvarchar(max))
--insert into splitstring values (N'One|Two|Three|Four')

select * 
from splitstring as t
cross apply dbo.split(string, '|') as ss
```

[image]